# React Router not working and Warning: You tried to redirect to the same route you're currently on: "/"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, single-page-application

I am new to react router and I cannot get it to work properly. I am building an SPA that has frame with header, sidebar and footer and the central view is supposed to change based on the selected path.

The top down DOM hierarchy is as follows:

index.js

```
render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>, 
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App.jsx

```
render() {
    return (
        <div >
            <Router history={history}>
                <div>
                    <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={DashboardLayout} />
                    <Route path="/#/login" component={LoginForm} />
                </div>
            </Router>
        </div >
    );
}
```

Dashboard.jsx

```
render() {
    if (this.state.toLogin === true) {
        return <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/#/login', state: { from: this.props.location } }} />
    }
    return (
        <div className="app">
            <AppHeader fixed>
                <DefaultHeader/>
            </AppHeader>
            <div className="app-body">
                <AppSidebar fixed display="lg">
                    <AppSidebarHeader />
                    <AppSidebarForm />

                    <AppSidebarFooter />
                    <AppSidebarMinimizer />
                </AppSidebar>
                <main className="main">
                    <Container fluid>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route path="/#/items" name="Items" component={ItemsTable} />
                            <Route path="/#/profile" name="Profile" component={ProfileManager} />
                            <Redirect from="/" to="/#/items" />
                        </Switch>
                    </Container>
                </main>
            </div>
            <AppFooter>
                <DefaultFooter />
            </AppFooter>
        </div>
    );
}
```

The PrivateRoute component is simply checking if the user is already logged in an eventually redirecting to the login form.

Once login I expect to see in the central view (wrapped by Container) ItemTables view but this is not happening.

Furthermore if navigate to /#/items or /#/profile manually (by entering the path on the browser or clicking in the UI) the central view in the Container doesn't change.

I do get an error saying:

```
Warning: You tried to redirect to the same route you're currently on: "/"
```

All the time and I suspect it is related.

Finally I am using Redux.

Thanks in advance for your help.

I am available to provide further details if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap them in Switch instead of div:

```
<Router history={history}>
   <Switch>
      <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={DashboardLayout} />
      <Route path="/#/login" component={LoginForm} />
    </Switch>
 </Router>
```

**When you're redirecting to same path with additional `#url`, it's necessary to have `exact path="/"`.** And you already have it. Which is absolutely correct. Make sure to other routes as well it uses exact path when you're redirecting to same path but with additional `#hashurl`.

---

How is Switch different than bunch of routes just wrapping them with a div?

`/path`, `/:alias`, `/path#hashurl`, and without path props will render all components because they match the location path.

But using Switch, you make sure not to include them all. Just match the route which match the location path.

---

Also, you're using the path without trailing slash like `path="/#/items"` and to match this you need to have `strict` and `exact` props together.

Example:

```
<Route exact strict strict path="/#/items"
```

Otherwise, you may have to use path with trailing slash:

```
<Route exact path="/#/items/"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I did wrap them into a Switch but no result. Same behavior and same warning...

Comment: Yes I did. No result :( The code in the description is also updated

Comment: I did like you said. Added a Switch and added exact to all routes. However it is still behaving like before. Thanks for the help but I don't think this is the root cause

Comment: I will find out. But can you tell me which route exactly having the issue as per my hint?

Comment: the warning is showed when I render Dashboard layout. Here is my code now: 

<Router history={history}>
                    <Switch>
                        <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={DashboardLayout} />
                        <Route exact path="/#/login" component={LoginForm} />
                    </Switch>
                </Router>

<Switch>
                                <Route exact path="/#/items" name="Items" component={ItemsTable} />
                                <Redirect from="/" to="/#/items" />
                            </Switch>

Comment: Try `<Route exact strict path="/#/items"`

Answer (score 0):

it's a little bit harder to reproduce your issue with the given code. if you can create a sandbox that could be great. Anyway, I created a sandbox with the hashrouter.
One thing I like to mention is that you don't have to mention the # on routes.

such as

```
<Switch>
  <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={DashboardLayout} />
  <Route path="/#/login" component={LoginForm} />
</Switch>
```

can be :

```
<Switch>
  <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={DashboardLayout} />
  <Route path="/login" component={LoginForm} />
</Switch>
```

hash is used as the reference to find the application path in static web apps.

If you want you can use the `Browserrouter` instead in `react router`

here is a working example I forked from another example. I added the `hashrouter` in this and hope this will help you.

- please find how the `<switch>` is used to wrap every route
- and find how the nested routing such as roster is achieved in the example

Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/25okp1mny

refernce: https://medium.com/@pshrmn/a-simple-react-router-v4-tutorial-7f23ff27adf

Comment: history router is useful for server side rendering.